# Stripe Hosted Connect Custom Onboarding Not Completing In Test Mode

Tags: stripe-payments

I am testing Stripe's Hosted Connect Custom Onboarding flow. After I create an account Id and an account link, I send the user to Stripe's hosted onboarding site. I am currently in Test mode at Stripe.

I am able to fill out all the data in the app but when I hit submit it never completes. All I receive is a spinning wheel. Are you able to create account on the hosted site in test mode?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There were two issues I was having. The tutorial I followed from Stripe did not include a return_url and a refresh_url. The reason the page kept spinning is because it did not have anywhere to return. The code below shows these links.

```
var accountLink = await stripe.accountLinks.create({
    account: account.id,
    success_url: 'http://localhost:4242?success',
    failure_url: 'http://localhost:4242?failure',
    refresh_url: 'https://globalexchange.com/about',
    return_url: 'https://globalexchange.com',
    type: 'custom_account_verification',
    collect: 'eventually_due',
  });
```

The other issue I was having was on the Stripe Dashboard. On the dashboard there is an option that will show test data. This was turned off. All of the account created with the app still spinning were created in test mode and they are now visible with the tab turned on.

[image]